# How to evaluate rows based on column values?

Tags: r, operation

I have a table looking as the following:

```
ID  period 1 period 2 period 3 period 4
A     4       2        25       42
B     3       56        2       45
C     16      1        34       67
D     56      2         8       48
```

I want to check in R how many times(cols) in each row I get values lower than 10. For example in row A I have two values lower than 10.
Any ideas???

I used the quantile values and got the following:

> quantile(v[,2:5],na.rm=TRUE)
>      0%   25%   50%   75%  100% 
>    1.00  2.75 20.50 45.75 67.00

But this is not exactly what I need; I want to know the percentage (or count) of values below 10. I tried using the following and also didn´t work:

> limit
>        [1] 10
>   v$tot<-count(v,c("ID","period1","period2"),wt_var=limit)`

The first few rows of the actual dataset areas follows:

```
    id    1   2   3   4    5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17
1 xxxlll  61  36 277 462  211 182  45  41 128 174 179  87  18 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2 ccvvbb 281 340 592 455  496 348 422 491 408 548 596 611 570 580 530 602 614
3 ddffgr 587 964 895 866 1120 725 547  90 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4 rrteww 257 331 320 411  442 316 334 403 355 444 522 661 508 499 520 413 494
5 oiertw 261 NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: This is a fairly basic R question.  Can you share what you've tried, where you have looked and why/how it hasn't worked?  Right now it sounds like you want us to write your code for you. Also please try to make your question [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: It is....I just realized it after struggling for quite some time.Sorry!

Comment: Go ahead and post your answer here and accept it for posterity.

Comment: Here's a nice intro on subsetting [(LINK)](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/subset_R.htm)

Comment: I am new at this site and can´t understand the right way to write code neither find the indications to be clear or who to ask. Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'll add an answer in case the OP doesn't, but in this case I'd use `rowSums` and logical comparison...

```
# '-1' drops the ID column
x <- rowSums( df[ ,-1 ] < 10 )
names(x) <- df$ID
x
#A B C D 
#2 2 1 2
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. It worked for the exampledataset but not for my actual dataset. I am guessing because I have various NA values x results in a list of NA for each ID.

Comment: just add `na.rm = TRUE` ... `x <- rowSums( df[ ,-1 ] < 10 , na.rm = TRUE )`. Please read the documentation.